# Internet explorer 9 is not playing jQuery MP3 plugin

Tags: jquery, mp3

My jQuery MP3 plugin plays an MP3 file that is placed on a remote serve.it is playing it in Firefox.But when I try to play it in Internet explorer 9, it says.

```
Jplayer 2.1.0:id='jquery_jplayer_1':Error!
Media URL could not be loaded.
Check media URL is valid.
Context:Address of mp3 file that is placed remotely.
```

Answer (score 0):

did you upload your HTML page to web server? IE has security measure that forbids you from running scripts locally. Upload it to web server first.

Comment: @ahren
Mp3 URL:-
 mp3: 'http://lecion.blob.core.windows.net/sixty-vocab-files//UploadSound/7fd752a6-97ef-4a99-b324-a160295b8ac4/43/Kalimba.mp3'

Comment: i am running it locally.Should i upload it to web server to make it working in internet explorer?Do you think it will solve the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You should upload to web server OR host a web server ( Apache / XAMPP ) locally .

Comment: Locally i am using Default development server of Visual studio.isn't enough?